# Magento 1.9.0.1 url rewrite not working; $_product->getProductUrl() returns incomplete path

Tags: ajax, magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.9

I'm using `magento 1.9.0.1`, and I have a category that contains a category that contains products.

Magento has added a url rewrite with the request path as `/category1/category2/product`, however using `$_product->getProductUrl()` returns the path `/category1/product/`.

Even though this request path is not complete `'/category1/category2/product'`, there is a url rewrite for `/category1/product/` however it returns a 404 page not found error using an ajax request.

Its weird, if I go to the link manually, without using ajax, `/category1/product/`, it displays the product page, in a cms-no-route div block, and at the bottom shows the "Whoops, my bad!" block.

Some rewrites work for some categories, but others don't.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: it looks like the url rewrite for '/category1/product/' goes to a target path of '/catalog/product/view/id/63/category/12', which does not work.

Comment: another thing worth noting, is that there is the full path product url rewrite, which is not outputted by getProductUrl():  '/category1/category2/product/' which uses a target path of '/catalog/product/view/id/63/category/14'.  why would it use two different categories?

Comment: the target path with category/14 works, but the target path with 12 does not.

Comment: ok by looking at the id's of the categories, category/12 is '/category1/', and category/14 is '/category2/' in my example of '/category1/category2/product'.  so category12/ is the root category, and category/14 is the subcategory, of category12.

Comment: so it seems that unless the route goes to a the url page where the url contains the actual full path of the product url page, like /category1/category2/product = '/catalog/category/view/id/63/category/14', it doesn't work.  these links display a cms-no-route: '/catalog/category/view/id/63/', '/catalog/category/view/id/63/category/12'